# Visual Studio 2010 Reset Default Web Browser Everytime I (Un)Install An Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Why does Visual Studio 2010 change the default "View In Browser" setting back to the default browser every time I add or remove an Extension from the Extension Gallery? My default browser in Visual Studio (for use with "View in Browser") is not the same as the one I use in Windows.

The two actions seem like they should be completely unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a known bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/568469 . And it should be fixed in "the next version of Visual Studio" (whatever that means), as stated in other duplicates of the same bug.

In the 'alternatives' section there are some workarounds. I haven't tried them though.

There is a nice extension that can help to overcome this problem - `WoVS Default Browser Switcher` - you can look for it in VS gallery. That one always helps me with this issue.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know about this extension!  Very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. This might be a little off-topic, but they have another great one too: WoVS Quick Add Reference. PS I don't get any money from them! :)